# Usage of `? :` in Arduino's QR code generator

Tags: unicode, arduino, block, symbols

I'm trying to create a QR code generator using Arduino. but there is a line I cannot understand. any one can help me.My code is down below.

```
#include "qrcode.h"

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);

// Start time
uint32_t dt = millis();
const char* number = "NUMBER";
// Create the QR code
QRCode qrcode;
uint8_t qrcodeData[qrcode_getBufferSize(3)];
qrcode_initText(&qrcode, qrcodeData, 3, 3, number);

// Delta time
dt = millis() - dt;
Serial.print("QR Code Generation Time: ");
Serial.print(dt);
Serial.print("\n");

// Top quiet zone
Serial.print("\n\n\n\n");

for (uint8_t y = 0; y < qrcode.size; y++) {

    // Left quiet zone
    Serial.print("        ");

    // Each horizontal module
    for (uint8_t x = 0; x < qrcode.size; x++) {

        // Print each module (UTF-8 \u2588 is a solid block)
        Serial.print(qrcode_getModule(&qrcode, x, y) ? "\u2588\u2588": "  ");

    }

    Serial.print("\n");
}

// Bottom quiet zone
Serial.print("\n\n\n\n");
   }

    void loop() {

   }
```

I cant understand `Serial.print(qrcode_getModule(&qrcode, x, y) ? "\u2588\u2588": "  ");` this line. what is the meaning of this part. `"\u2588\u2588": "  "`. I know `\u2588` is a block symbol is in unicode. but what is the use of two double commas after the block symbols???

Comment: "two double commas after the block symbols" => Where? Sorry I don't see them. You mean the "colon" symbol?

Comment: in this line.    "\u2587\u2587": " "

Comment: what is the meaning of  double commas after colon

Comment: `"  "` are two space characters between double-quotes.

Comment: take pen and paper and break that statement down. it shouldn't take more than a minute for you to realize that there are operators you don't know. then google c++ operator ? and you're done. you'll learn the most if you actually think about a problem befor you ask for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't understand the [ternary operator `?:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

The construction `qrcode_getModule(&qrcode, x, y) ? "\u2588\u2588": "  "` means:

- if `qrcode_getModule(&qrcode, x, y)` can evaluate to the boolean "true" (here a non-null byte) then use the part before the colon : `"\u2588\u2588"` (`██`) (plain block)
- else (`qrcode_getModule(&qrcode, x, y) == 0`) then use the part after the colon : `"  "` (empty block)

Comment: By "choose" I meant "click the accept button". See This question: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @ddevz My pleasure :)